# Xampp opens MariaDB instead of MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using xampp for mySQL. However, when I opened mySQL in the command line, it opened MariaDB instead of mySQL. Is there any difference between MySQL and MariaDB? if yes, How can I switch back to MySQL? 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: In wikipedia it can tell you..

Comment: MariaDB is a community-developed fork of the MySQL relational database management system intended to remain free under the GNU GPL. Development is led by some of the original developers of MySQL, who forked it due to concerns over its acquisition by Oracle Corporation.Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB